# Number of rows indicated by KendoGrid does not equal number of rows in database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, oracle, kendo-ui

Presently, I am using a KendoGrid to display a fairly large number of rows, with paging.  It works myData; however, the total number of rows it returns is not the same as the number of rows in the database table that it queries.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult ExecuteTestRule(string ruleSql, string key, List<matchRuleParam> parameters)
    {
        if (Request.Url != null)
        {
            var dataSource = new MyDataSource();
            List<DataAccess.DbParameter> dbParameters = null;
            var generatedSql = dataSource.GenerateQuerySql(ruleSql, key, parameters, out dbParameters);

            List<string> uwis = dataSource.ExecuteTestRule(generatedSql, dbParameters);
            var myDataSet = new WellSetManager(Session.SessionID).Store(uwis);

            var response = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            response["wsid"] = myDataSet.Id;

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the code in my javascript file:

```
function execTestRule(key) {
    var parametersForSelectedRule = getParametersForSelectedRule();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "ExecuteTestRule",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ruleSql: PageState.SqlEditor.RuleSql.getValue(),
            key: "'" + key + "'",
            parameters: parametersForSelectedRule

        }),
        success: function (response) {

            Grids.TestRuleResultsGrid.resultViewGrid("refresh",
            {
                keySetId: response.wsid
            });

            PageState.Selected.ChildKey = null;
            PageState.TestRuleResult = true;
            updateButtonStates();
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            var errorObject = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
            var errorMessage = errorObject.Message;

            showErrorMessage(errorMessage, "Error");

        }
    });
}
```

Where,

```
        Grids.TestRuleResultsGrid = $("#test-rule-results-grid").resultViewGrid({
        viewId: "queryResults", 
        controllerUrl: getControllerUrl(navigation.controllers.resultView, ""),
        enableSelection: false,
        showChildGrids: false
```

Here are the options for resultViewGrid:

```
            var gridOptions = {
                dataSource: dataSource,
                selectable: true,
                sortable: true,
                scrollable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                filterable: true,
                columns: gridColumns,
                resizable: true
            };
```

Here is the data source for resultViewGrid:

```
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "{0}/ViewData".format(that.options.controllerUrl),
                        type: "get",
                        dataType: "json",
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(data) {
                        data.viewId = viewId;
                        data.joins = JSON.stringify(joins);

                        formatKendoParameterMapDates(data, function(fieldName) {
                            return dataSourceModel.fields[fieldName].type === "date";
                        });

                        return data;
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                        data: "mydata",
                        total: "total",
                        model: dataSourceModel
                },
                pageSize: childSettings.pageSize,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true
            });
```

The number of rows in the database is 81658 when I perform a COUNT SQL command:

```
select COUNT(*) from TEST_AREA where AREA_TYPE= 'COUNTRY' and ACTIVE_IND = 'Y';
```

The KendoGrid displays instead that there are 79973 rows:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the KendoGrid does not show the same number of rows as the Oracle database?

Comment: Could you please verify that. How many records are available in kendo datasource?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @Jayesh Goyani.  Please see the answer I found below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a data problem--the table has some duplicate key values, so the application deep down in the data access layer was removing those duplicates before displaying the results in the KendoGrid.  Here is the query that shows the correct number of records, which is what the grid was showing:

select COUNT(*) from (select DISTINCT KEY from TEST_AREA where AREA_TYPE= 'COUNTRY' and ACTIVE_IND = 'Y');